# How can I save my InvisionApp prototype as an android studio/eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, prototype

I m using invisionApp (http://invisionapp.com) and I have finished a prototype. Now can I make this prototype so I can edit it in android studio? Or are these prototypes just to plan your design?
Thanks